OpenID Connect Callback Path Issues with .NET Core Application on EKS
I am encountering issues with OpenID Connect authentication in my .NET Core application after deploying it to AWS EKS. The authentication works correctly locally but fails when deployed. Here are the details of the setup and the problems I'm facing:
Setup:
.NET Core version: .NET 6
Authentication: OpenID Connect with OAM
Deployment environment: AWS EKS
Redirecturl: https://admin.aws.xxx.com/test
Callback Path:/
I tried changing the call back path to /test instead of / but i redirects to home page but doesnt really go through the authentication flow.
Relevant code:
#region Auth
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    
})
#region OAM
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Configuration = GetOpenIdConnectConfigurations(configuration).Result;
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        options.ClientId = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:ClientId");
        options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
        options.ClientSecret = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:ClientSecret");
        options.CallbackPath = "/";

        options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true;
        options.UsePkce = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.AuthenticationType = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
        };

        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
        {
            Log.Information("Redirecting to Identity Provider for sign in.");
            await OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignIn(context, configuration);
        };
        options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
        {
            Log.Information("Authorization code received.");
            await OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(context, configuration);
        };
        options.Events.OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            Log.Information("Token validated.");
            return OnTokenValidated(context);
        };
        options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
        {
            Log.Information("Redirecting to Identity Provider for sign out.");
            await OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut(context, configuration);
        };
        options.Events.OnAccessDenied = context =>
        {
            Log.Warning("Access denied.");
            return OnAccessDenied(context);
        };
        options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            Log.Error("Remote failure: {ErrorMessage}", context.Failure.Message);
            return OnRemoteFailure(context);
        };

        options.Scope.Clear();
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add(configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:Scope"));
        options.SaveTokens = true;
    });
#endregion
#endregion

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}



app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});


app.Run();

#region Methods

Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignIn(RedirectContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Log.Information("OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignIn called.");
    context.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("domain", configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:DomainName"));
    var hostName = context.Request.Host.Value.ToLowerInvariant();
    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = GetRedirectURL(configuration, hostName);
    Log.Information("Redirect URI: {RedirectUri}", context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Log.Information("OnAuthorizationCodeReceived called.");
    try
    {
        var oamConfiguration = await context.Options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, oamConfiguration.TokenEndpoint);

        var hostName = context.Request.Host.Value.ToLowerInvariant();
        var redirectUrl = GetRedirectURL(configuration, hostName);
        Log.Information("Authorization Code Redirect URL: {RedirectUrl}", redirectUrl);

        context.TokenEndpointRequest.RedirectUri = redirectUrl;

        using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-OAUTH-IDENTITY-DOMAIN-NAME", configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:DomainName"));
        string codeVerifier = context.TokenEndpointRequest.Parameters.Where(x => x.Key == "code_verifier").FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var tokenClientOptions = new TokenClientOptions()
        {
            ClientId = context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = context.TokenEndpointRequest.ClientSecret,
            Address = oamConfiguration.TokenEndpoint,
            Parameters = {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            }
        };

        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(httpClient, tokenClientOptions);
        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync(context.TokenEndpointRequest.Code, redirectUrl, codeVerifier);
        if (tokenResponse.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            context.HandleCodeRedemption(tokenResponse.AccessToken, tokenResponse.IdentityToken);
            Log.Information("Token response received and handled successfully.");
            Log.Information("Access Token: {AccessToken},Identity Token: {IdentityToken}", tokenResponse.AccessToken, tokenResponse.IdentityToken);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Error("Failed to get response from token endpoint: {TokenResponse}", tokenResponse);
            throw new Exception($"Unable to get response from token endpoint... {tokenResponse}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "Exception occurred during authorization code received.");
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
    }

    await Task.FromResult(0);
}

string GetRedirectURL(IConfiguration configuration, string hostName)
{
    Log.Information("GetRedirectURL called for host: {HostName}", hostName);
    var redirectUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:RedirectUrl");
    return redirectUrl;
}

async Task<OpenIdConnectConfiguration> GetOpenIdConnectConfigurations(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Log.Information("Getting OpenIdConnect configurations.");
    try
    {
        using var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-OAUTH-IDENTITY-DOMAIN-NAME", configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:DomainName"));
        var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:MetadataAddress"), new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(), client);
        var openIdConnectConfiguration = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();
        Log.Information("OpenIdConnect configurations retrieved successfully.");
        return openIdConnectConfiguration;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "Unable to get configurations from OAM.");
        throw new Exception($"Unable to get configurations from OAM: {ex}");
    }
}

async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut(RedirectContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    Log.Information("OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut called.");
    var oamConfiguration = await context.Options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    var logoutUrl = configuration.GetValue<string>("Authentication:OAM:AppSignOutUrl");
    context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = oamConfiguration.Issuer;
    context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = logoutUrl;
    Log.Information("Sign out redirect URL: {LogoutUrl}", logoutUrl);
    context.Response.Redirect(logoutUrl, true);
    context.HandleResponse();
}

Task OnRemoteFailure(RemoteFailureContext context)
{
    Log.Error("Remote failure occurred: {ErrorMessage}", context.Failure.Message);
    context.HandleResponse();
    string errorMessage = $"Single sign-on Remote Failure - {context.Failure.Message}. Please Retry";
    context.Response.Redirect($"/Error?message={Uri.EscapeDataString(errorMessage)}");
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

Task OnAccessDenied(AccessDeniedContext context)
{
    Log.Warning("Access denied.");
    context.HandleResponse();
    string errorMessage = "Single sign-on AccessDenied";
    context.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Forbidden?message={Uri.EscapeDataString(errorMessage)}");
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

Task OnTokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    Log.Information("Token validated successfully.");
    context.Properties.StoreTokens(new[] {
        new AuthenticationToken
        {
            Name = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            Value = context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken,
        }
    });

    var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    Log.Information("User ID claim: {UserIdClaim}", userIdClaim.Value);

    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userIdClaim.Value));

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}

#endregion

You have some logging going on in the OIDC callbacks. Are any of them being hit?

OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignIn I see this method is being called after this it directly loads the page without hitting OnAuthorizationCodeReceived and OnTokenValidated. So it doesnt really auhtneticate the user
